# GWT History.back() is not firing onValueChangeHandler

Tags: javascript, gwt, browser-history

I have a Previous button in my  GWT application , to which i have attached an event handler which calls the **History.back()**.

```
eventBus.addHandler(PrevEvent.TYPE, new PrevEventHandler() {
        public void onNext(PrevEvent prevEvent) {
            History.back();
            System.out.println("Token is" +History.getToken());

        }
    });
```

When the event is fired i can see the URL token being changed in the browser, but the **History.getToken()** is printing the recent token itself.
For eg, if the tokens were added in the order **#A, #B, #C**, when i click previous when i'm in **#C** the URL changes to **#B**, but the getToken says its **#C.** 
I think this is causing the problem of no call to the **onValueChange** method and hence my app stays the same.

The same is observed when i try with the back button of the browser. I'm using firefox, but behaviour in other browsers is no different.

What might be the reason?

My perception was that **History.back()** would also fire the **onValueChange()**, now it seems that only **History.newItem()** would do be able to do the job then . Correct me if i am wrong. I am confused. How do i handle the **previous**  button events then ?

```
       eventBus.addHandler(PrevEvent.TYPE, new PrevEventHandler() {
        public void onNext(PrevEvent prevEvent) {
            History.back();
            System.out.println("Token is" +History.getToken());
            doPrev();
        }
    });


    private void doPrev(){
       System.out.println("Calling Previous Method");
 }
```

Somewhere in my app, my code with the current history token #Step3 fires the previous event. So when it comes to the previous event, i execute the History.back() and i expect the token to be back to #Step2 and i have the onValueChange method like this,

```
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {

    String token = event.getValue();

    if(token != null){
         presenter = null;

    if(token == "step1")
    {
        System.out.println("Step 1");
        //do Something

    }
    else if(token == "step2")
    {
        System.out.println("Step 2");
                    //do Something      
    }
            else if(token == "step3")
    {
        System.out.println("Step 3");
                    //do Something      
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like History.back() takes a loong time (literally loong, about lOO millis :))

I wrote some code to test it:

```
    public void onModuleLoad()
{
    History.newItem("A");
    History.newItem("B");
    History.newItem("C");
    RootPanel.get().add(new Button("back", new ClickHandler()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(
            ClickEvent event)
        {
            System.out.println("After back click token is " + History.getToken());
            History.back();
            new Timer()
            {

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    System.out.println("After 100 millis token is " + History.getToken());
                }
            }.schedule(100);
        }
    }));
    History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>()
    {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(
            ValueChangeEvent<String> event)
        {
            System.out.println("We handle ValueChangeEvent on History. Now token is " + History.getToken());
        }
    });
}
```

Output in google chrome was follows

```
After back click token is C
After 100 millis token is C
We handle ValueChangeEvent on History. Now token is B
After back click token is B
We handle ValueChangeEvent on History. Now token is A
After 100 millis token is A
After back click token is A
We handle ValueChangeEvent on History. Now token is C
After 100 millis token is C
```

It is no answer you wanted, but it is too big for comment :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have problems trying out your solution though, nevertheless if History.back() takes too much time to execute, and subsequent steps follow before its executing, What do you think is a feasible solution for this problem.?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? History does not fire valueChangeEvent?

Comment: Exactly, History.back() is not firing the valueChangeEvent !

Comment: Do you handle events the same way like in my code? If no, attach your code please. As can be seen from output History.back() does fire events.

Comment: I have added the code above. I handle the events pretty much in the same way. In my case my History.back(), doesn't fire onValueChange.

And in the History.getToken() right after the History.back() , it prints the earlier token from where the previous event(from step 3) was called. That is it still showing step3 whereas i expect it to be changed to step2 and call the onValueChange, which is not happening. 

I understand that History.back() takes a while to act, so how to delay this so that my onValueChange can catch this change in the history token

Comment: Does gwt gistory get initialized at all? Field impl in class History  is not equal to null?

Comment: It is getting initialized. History works well when i'm adding new tokens, onValueChange is getting fired on newToken, but the problem is with the History.back()

Comment: The last thing I can suggest is DOM function onhashchange was overridden in some other place. Do you use pure GWT without any frameworks which may provide own history mechanism?

Comment: Pure GWT Framework  and nothing else. No jar except the GWT 2.4 dev

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13780/discussion-between-napster-and-sinicyn)